# WPF/GDI interop: how do I get correct alpha?

Tags: wpf, interop

I've created a semi-transparent test image, filled with 128-alpha black. I draw it while alternating between two methods: WPF native and GDI interop. They come out completely different; the WPF one is done correctly, but the GDI appears to be blended against white first, before being drawn:

[image: example 1]

If drawn against a photo, the GDI part *lightens* what's below it, even though a 0,0,0,128 color should darken whatever is below it:

[image: example 2]

The code goes like this:

```
if (iteration % 2 == 0)
    context.DrawImage(new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("I:/test.png")),
                      new Rect(0, 0, 80, 24));
else
{
    var bmp = (D.Bitmap) D.Bitmap.FromFile("I:/test.png");
    var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
    var bmpSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    context.DrawImage(bmpSource, new Rect(0, 0, 80, 24));
    WinAPI.DeleteObject(handle);
    GC.KeepAlive(bmp);
}
```

For the second image, I changed the Rect size for the WPF one to show that they don't overlap.

How do I draw a semi-transparent GDI image correctly?

(yes, it really has to be a GDI image for complex reasons - in reality it doesn't come from a file, but from some external code, but the problem is reproduceable easily with a file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled on avoiding this call now, and just copying the raw bitmap data over. The code:

```
var writable = new WriteableBitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
                      bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution,
                      PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

writable.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                      data.Scan0, data.Stride * bmp.Height, data.Stride);

GC.KeepAlive(bmp);
context.DrawImage(writable, new Rect(0, 0, 80, 24));
```

(this might need a `using` or two)

Also, if the writable bitmap is used directly as a source for something like `Image` then a call to `Freeze` helps prevent flicker on update, though I don't see why it would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I draw a semi-transparent GDI image correctly?

Like this:

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = ...
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(targetBitmap))
    g.DrawImage(...);
```

In other words, don’t bother with the GDI-to-WPF interop (it’s clearly not working). Save the intermediate bitmaps to files and use WPF-only when you need WPF and GDI-only when you need GDI.

Comment: Well at least you aren't suggesting I use JPEG as my intermediate format... Believe it or not, but there are a bunch of search hits that suggest exactly that!...